# npm install -g expo-cli not completing installation

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, nvm

I am trying to install the expo-cli using nvm but for some reason it will get to a certain point during installation and then just stop.

I have tried using different node versions along with trying to remove the permissions that could of potentially been blocking the installation but still no luck. This is what shows in the console:

```
npm WARN deprecated joi@14.0.4: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/sup
port). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable
to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated @babel/polyfill@7.4.4: ? As of Babel 7.4.0, this
npm WARN deprecated package has been deprecated in favor of directly
npm WARN deprecated including core-js/stable (to polyfill ECMAScript
npm WARN deprecated features) and regenerator-runtime/runtime
npm WARN deprecated (needed to use transpiled generator functions):
npm WARN deprecated
npm WARN deprecated   > import "core-js/stable";
npm WARN deprecated   > import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
npm WARN deprecated joi@11.4.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/sup
port). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable
to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated topo@2.0.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/sup
port). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable
to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/sup
port). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable
to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated topo@3.0.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/topo. Please update your dependencie
s as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
npm WARN deprecated hoek@6.1.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/hoek. Please update your dependencie
s as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @expo/traveling-fastlane-linux@1.9.11 (sha512-xCHnqKfwWYygQfRbi9MGNSG28EHKDtzMB+QDklSH
1GeD90TA0beAjlNF+Z+KPxj28s3WZlQr9yw1AqBS7aipcw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `sudo` before running `nvm install` command? that's if you are using Mac or Linux

Comment: I am currently on windows 10 and using powershell. I have been running powershell as an administrator also if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Which terminal are you using ? If it's GitBash so the issue arises there try using any other terminal and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem ("tarball data for @expo/traveling-fastlane-linux@1.9.11 seems to be corrupted") on the command line (instead of powershell) on Windows 10, and running cmd as administrator solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. It looks like is a permission issue. Following the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally) I reinstall npm with a node version manager. As I'm a linux user, I use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) (check the documentation to chose the adequate manager for your system).

After uninstalled both npm and node, I ran:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.1/install.sh | bash
```

Check installation using:

```
command -v nvm
```

The output must be `nvm`.

Finally, run:

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```